# Why do I need an explicit casting to short for an integer literal in the ternary operator?

Tags: c#, type-conversion

```
static void Main()
{
    short x = 3;/* no need explicit casting (short)3 */
    Console.WriteLine(Factorial(x));
}
static short Factorial(short x)
{
    return x == 0 ? 
        (short)1 /* need explicit casting (short)1 */
        :
        (short)(x * Factorial((short)(x - 1)));
}
```

Why do I need an explicit casting to `short` for an integer literal in the ternary operator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answers have good ideas in them but none precisely characterizes the actual problem. That's because you have discovered a rather subtle problem! I discovered the same problem in 2006 when I was first working on the conditional operator in the context of getting type inference working in LINQ. My series of articles on the subject can be found here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/type-inference-woes-part-one

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2006/05/26/type-inference-woes-part-two.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2006/05/30/type-inference-woes-part-three.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2006/07/18/type-inference-woes-part-four.aspx

The first two are relevant to the conditional operator.

Comment: I hate to risk looking like a fool for questioning you, but are you sure this is still the problem? The example you used in the first article of what should compile but doesn't, namely `short s = 123; int i = (a > b) ? 0 : s;`, which is indeed exactly what this question is about, is accepted by current versions of both Microsoft's and Mono's compilers without any problems.

Comment: @hwd: Hah, good catch. I meant to go back and update that article with the fix that was eventually decided on and apparently I never did! Too late now.  I will add some more notes to explain the situation more fully in this answer when I'm back at my desk.

Answer (score 5):

The type of a `(bool) ? (short) : (int)` expression is `int`, even if the `(int)` sub-expression is constant and within the range of `short`.

There is a special exception where `int` can implicitly convert to `short` when it is constant and within range, but your full expression isn't constant, so that exception doesn't apply, and the language designers never added other similar exceptions, probably because they would only rarely be useful.

Answer (score 2):

Because there is no implicit conversation from `int` to `short` (if the value is `constant` and acceptable range, there is by the way). Take a look at [`Implicit Numeric Conversions Table (C# Reference)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5b434w4.aspx)

From [`?: Operator (C# Reference)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx)

```
condition ? first_expression : second_expression;
```

> Either the type of first_expression and second_expression must be the
>   same, **or an implicit conversion must exist from one type to the other**

**EDIT**: hdv is right about [what the actual problem is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22115204/why-do-i-need-an-explicit-casting-to-short-for-an-integer-literal-in-the-ternary#comment33549717_22115262). It is the problem with return statement (return type). For example;

```
var i = x == 0 ?
      1 
      :
      (short)(x * Method((short)(x - 1)));
```

is a valid expression. But `i` will be an `int`. Since your *return type* is `short`, that's the point of the error.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. An implicit conversion from `short` to `int` does exist, so the `?:` expression is valid, it just has type `int` instead of `short`.

Comment: @hvd An implicit conversion from `short` to `int` exist **but** an implicit conversion from `int` to `short` does not exist. This is happening here. `1` is an `int` as a default. `?:` expects `short` as a _first_expression_ because it's definition (_return type_ of method is `short`).

Comment: An implicit conversion from int to short does exist (when the value is a constant and in the range of short, which is the case here), but `?:` doesn't expect anything as its second and third operands' type. It doesn't pay attention to the fact that the context is a return statement and the return type is `short`. It only pays attention to the fact that it has an `int` operand, and a `short` operand, so implicitly converts the `short` operand to `int`. The result, then, is a valid expression of type `int`. The only problem is that *that* cannot implicitly be converted back to `short`.

Comment: @hvd You are right about the conversation part. It is convertable when it is `constant` and acceptable range. Added this detail to my answer. Thank you. But, as you said in [your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22115253/447156), OP's code does not have _constant expression_ in this part. Language does not allow that.

Comment: Right, I thought your answer was still based on the lack of an implicit conversion from `1` to `short`, but your edit clears that up.

Answer (score 1):

while using conditional operator `?:` both expressions must evaluate to the same `type` if not implicit conversion should be possile.

here there is no implicit conversion can happen between `int` to `short` so you need explicit conversion.

From MSDN : [`?: Operator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx)

> Either the type of first_expression and second_expression must be the
>   same, or an implicit conversion must exist from one type to the other.

**EDIT:**

**Explanation:**

**Rule 1:** the types of first and second expression must be either same type or implicitly convertable.

from the above rule it is perfectly valid if you write the same satetement using conditional
operator as below:

```
var result = ( x == 0 ) ? 1 : (short)(x * Method((short)(x - 1)));
```

**Reason:**

=> constant  1 in first expression  is `int`.
=> your second expression result evaluates to int.(remember any arithmetic operations on byte or short makes the outcome as int)

so now as both expressions are evaluated to type `int` hence you don't need any casting and compiler does not force you for casting.

Now let us see your question

> Why do I need an explicit casting to short for an integer literal in
>   the ternary operator?

it is as simple as that because your function return type is `short` you need to return `short`

Comment: No, both expressions don't need to evaluate to the same type. You're already quoting where MSDN says they don't need to.

Comment: ...and after your edit, it still doesn't answer the question, because an implicit conversion *is* possible, just not in the direction the OP was hoping for.

Comment: how come implicit conversion from `int` to `short` can happen? sorry i didnt get your point

Comment: The `?:` expression is valid, because it performs an implicit conversion from `short` to `int`. The only problem is that a non-constant `int` expression is not valid in a `return` statement when the return type is `short`. That's where the problem is, the problem isn't with the `?:`.

Comment: Yes dear :) got it. it is forcing for casting due to the fact that the expected `return` type is `short` but not because of implicit conversion problem. as 1 (int) constant can always be implicitly converted to int as it is a constant.

Comment: @hvd: so if he write the same conditional operator statement without return statement it is perfectly valid IMO.

Comment: Exactly. Outside of the context of the `return` statement, the expression would be valid (assuming I've made no typos here): `var result = x == 0 ? 1 : (short)(x * Method((short)(x - 1)));` would give `result` type `int`, without any errors. But a following `return result;` would then be rejected for probably obvious reasons.

Comment: @hvd: Thanks dear :) you taught me new topic today -> `A constant expression of type int can be converted to short provided the value of the constant expression is within the range of the destination type.` Thank you :)